# creating a folder automatically for each user in Django + saving tensorflow weights in that folder

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

So I want to create a folder automatically for each user, Here is my models.py:

models.py

```
#Creating a folder automatically for each user
def folder_path(instance, filename):
    return "user_{0}/MyFolder/{1}".format(instance.user.id, filename)



# Create your models here.
class SLRModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default= None)
    my_folder = models.FileField(upload_to= folder_path, default= None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1:

### Option 1

[from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model): you can go for **Custom User Model**. It goes something like this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    weights_dir = models.CharField('Weights Directory')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.weights_dir is None:
            self.weights_dir = "user_{0}/MyFolder/{1}".format(self.id, self.username)
            # add creating directory code here

        super(AbstractUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in `settings.py` set

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourappname.MyUser'
```

you will also need to updated the `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Don't forget to migrate after these changes.

### Option 2

If you are not comfortable impleminting a Custom user model and want to go with default one you can using post_save signal, [from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save). Something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_directory(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        pass # add create directory code here
```

---

### Answer 2:

In `views.py` you can do something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    # add wigths save code here
    return HttpResponse("Weights Created.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Creating a folder automatically for each user
def folder_path(instance, filename):
    user = instance.user.username
    basename, file_extension = filename.split(".")
    new_filename = "%s-%s.%s" %(user, instance.id, file_extension)
    return "MyFolder/%s/%s" %(user, new_filename)


# Create your models here.
class SLRModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default= None)
    my_folder = models.FileField(upload_to= folder_path, default= None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How do I call it in views.py, if I want to create the folder, before saving anything to it?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve in short?

Comment: Kindly take a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) . Hopefully you'll get helpful.

Comment: I realized where I was mistaken, now last question I want to just call the function to create the folder for the user, what/how do I call it in views.py. Thanks